# Laravel 5 - 3 forms on the same page

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.1

I am beginer with Laravel, I need help please.

In my edit user page, I have 3 forms.
But I can not do in my rooter how to make it work.

My code (in Routes) :

```html
<?php
// update role
Route::post('edit/{id}', [
 'as' => 'user_post_update_role', 
 'uses' => 'UserController@updateRole'
]);
// update infos
Route::post('edit/{id}', [
 'as' => 'user_post_update', 
 'uses' => 'UserController@update'
]);
// update password.
Route::post('edit/{id}', [
 'as' => 'user_post_update_password', 
 'uses' => 'UserController@updatePassword'
]);
?>
```

But the last rule, Block others.

How to do ?
Thank

Comment: Modify your routes so that each form has its own url, e.g. edit/role/{id}, edit/info/{id}.  Or use a single route and use an if/else statement to determine if the form is role, info, or password.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Edit your route like this:

```
// update role
Route::post('edit/{id}/role', [
    'as' => 'user_post_update_role', 
    'uses' => 'UserController@updateRole'
]);
// update infos
Route::post('edit/{id}/main', [
    'as' => 'user_post_update', 
    'uses' => 'UserController@update'
]);
// update password.
Route::post('edit/{id}/password', [
    'as' => 'user_post_update_password', 
    'uses' => 'UserController@updatePassword'
]);
```

So you have unique routes and don't need complicate if else statements.

Comment: Ok thank. But It's not good.
by what if I made a error during POST, exampl (if error password):
http://www.creerwebsite.com/medias/upload/111.png
the URL becomes is like this: http://www.creerwebsite.com/medias/upload/222.png
so error: http://www.creerwebsite.com/medias/upload/333.png

Comment: You can use return `Redirect::back()->withErrors([]);` Or you have one Route for all and inside the method you make an if statement and call the other functions like `this->updatePassword($request);`

Comment: You can redirect back with an error message like this: `return Redirect::back()->withErrors(['your-field' => 'the error message you want to display']);`

Comment: Yes, I have use a alternative function. Thank

Answer (score 1):

The only way to do this, would be to have a single route, and have the controller that handles that route identify which form was submitted.

What you're basically doing with those routes, is defining three routes that for all intents and purposes, are identical. Therefore, it'll only use the last one that was created as each new one, overwrites its predecessor.

Alternatively, you could do as it says in the comment on your post, use `edit/{id}` for updating user info, `edit/password/{id}` for updating password, and `edit/role/{id}` for updating the role. You could even break these out into separate methods entirely, or separate sections.

Of the many ways you can achieve this, your chosen method is unfortunately not amongst them.